# Send import notification email to multiple email addresses?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've created an import to Marketing Cloud from a Sales Cloud report.

I would like for the import notification email to be sent to multiple people.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

I have tried:
person@email.com,person2@email.com
person@email.com;person2@email.com

But both come up with the error "Enter a valid email address"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Distribution List(DL) with required email addresses in the place of notification email address.

You may need to contact the email administrator of your organization if you dont have the privilage to create one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).